# When to use aggregation, association?

Tags: uml, class-diagram, tool-uml

- is there any why to know which one of two types of interaction
  mentioned[aggregation or association] should be used in class diagram
  ?
- is it even matter to specify which one to use in a certain interaction ?

Answer (score 0):

**Assosiation**

      The most abstract way to describe static relationship between classes is using the Association link, which simply states that there is some kind of a link or a dependency between two classes or more.
**Aggregation**
      
In cases where there’s a part-of relationship between ClassA (whole) and ClassB (part), we can be more specific and use the aggregation link instead of the association link, highlighting that the same ClassB instance can also be aggregated by other classes in the application (therefore aggregation is also known as shared association).


If you want to read detailed description then check this [LINK](http://aviadezra.blogspot.in/2009/05/uml-association-aggregation-composition.html)

Comment: i read the article u posted and it really helped me to have some kinda certainty about the use of association and aggregation, and i feel like there is no need to put any aggregation interaction in the diagram at all because association can replace it !, thanks